# Attachment name in Outlook looks wrong (encoding issue?)

Tags: outlook, components, pipeline, biztalk

I hope someone can point us out to the issue in our code. Take a look at the picture.
[image]

As you can see the attachment name is ALMOST as expected. We want the name to be 'Anmälan-A00045.pdf' and 'Anmälan-45tg.pdf'. If I save the attachment the name is shown correctly. I believe that I am setting the encoding wrong somewhere. Trying to dump the mail as a file leads to the following output.

> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
> boundary="*8EC249FE-78A0-420A-98D9-D953E58A8F9E*"
>
> --*8EC249FE-78A0-420A-98D9-D953E58A8F9E*
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> Content-ID: {4EE462B2-16FB-47AE-A318-1C2C6ED889D3}
> Content-Description: body
>
> (body of email above and below is the attachment stuff)
>
> --*8EC249FE-78A0-420A-98D9-D953E58A8F9E*
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Type: application/pdf
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
> Content-ID: {F4F32EDB-36AF-4DAE-982A-93C3BF0F59C6}
> Content-Description: Anmälan-45tg.pdf
> Content-Disposition: attachment;
> filename="=?utf-8?B?QW5tw6RsYW4tNDV0Zy5wZGZ=?="

We are using Biztalk with a custom send pipeline (containing our pipeline component and the mime/smime in encoding stage) to send out an email using SMTP-adapter. Now, as with many other posts in SO, this works perfect in other email clients like Gmail or Hotmail.

Now, code snippet below is what I am using to set the attachments and everything related to it. Does anyone have an idea of what to try? My trials with the method HtmlEncode did nothing, unfortunately.

```
public void ProcessAttachments(IPipelineContext _pContext, IBaseMessage _msg, 
IList<Attachment> _attachments)
    {
        foreach (var item in _attachments)
        {
            var msgPart = _pContext.GetMessageFactory().CreateMessagePart();

            msgPart.PartProperties.Write("FileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", item.FileName + item.Extension);
            msgPart.PartProperties.Write("ContentDescription", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", item.ContentType);

            // MIME / SMIME content transfer encoding
            msgPart.PartProperties.Write("ContentTransferEncoding", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", Encoding.UTF8);

            msgPart.Data = new MemoryStream(BytesFromBase64String(item.Base64));
            msgPart.ContentType = item.ContentType;  
            //msgPart.Charset = "UTF-8";

            //_msg.AddPart(HtmlEncode(item.FileName + item.Extension), msgPart, false);
            _msg.AddPart(item.FileName + item.Extension, msgPart, false); 
        }
    }

    private static string HtmlEncode(string filename)
    {
        /* Old code. What this does is change 'ä' to '&#228;' Matters little as Outlook intreprets it literally. The filename in Outlook is set as 'Anm&#228;lan-45tg.pdf'.
        string result;
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var x = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            x.WriteEncodedText(filename);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }
        return result;
        */

        var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(filename);
        return utf8.GetString(utfBytes);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried UTF16 instead of UTF8 to encode the filename?

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf. Yes, we have tried to use this piece of code in ProcessAttachments:
// MIME / SMIME content transfer encoding
                msgPart.PartProperties.Write("ContentTransferEncoding", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", Encoding.UTF32);
     ... 
                _msg.AddPart(HtmlEncode(item.FileName + item.Extension), msgPart, false);

...and in HtmlEncode: var utf8 = Encoding.UTF32;

Usage of UTF16 gives MIMEException, for some reason.

Comment: What really surprises me is that I tried to send the same mail to our consultant compnay which also uses Outlook. That same mail is interpreted correctly. Have asked the tech support for some assitance. Might be some issue with a setting in Outlook at the customer's.

Comment: The sample dump has the correct Base-64 encoding of the correct UTF-8 encoding of the file name, though it is not RFC2047 compliant since the encoding scheme used is prohibited within Content-Disposition parameters and quoted strings (other mail senders also violate this), should use RFC2231. You say that it saves under the correct name. The name shown in the picture is exactly what would be shown if the UTF-8 were being treated as ISO-8859-1 (aka extended ASCII). The problem seems to be that Outlook is displaying attachment names as 8-bit characters.